# how to follow a recursive isBST function?

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to follow a specific implementation of a recursive (in-order traversal) isBST function.

I tried to simulate it with the simple invalid BST example:
root=5, root.left=3, root.left.right=8

```
  5
 /
3
 \
  8
```

i'm getting either 'true' or 'false' but without having to check the last node '8'.
the code is as follows:

```
/* wrapper that keeps track of the previous value */
class PrevWrapper {
    int data = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}

boolean isBST(Node root, PrevWrapper prev) {
    /* base case: we reached null*/
    if (root == null) {
        return true;
    }

    if(!isBST(root.left, prev)) {
        return false;
    }

    /* If previous in-order node's data is larger than
     * current node's data, BST property is violated */
    if (prev.data > root.data) {
        return false;
    }

    /* set the previous in-order data to the current node's data*/
    prev.data = root.data;

    return isBST(root.right, prev);
}

boolean isBST(Node root) {
    return isBST(root, new PrevWrapper());
}
```

what is the correct order of returning the recursive calls?

**EDIT**:

I was thinking:
(#)isBST(5,min), isBST(3,min), isBST(3.left=null,min) - returns true, skips to prev=3, isBST(8,3), isBST(8.left=null,3) - returns true, skips to prev=8, isBST(8.right=null,8) - returns true to (#), **checks 8 > 5? returns false**.

I think I got it, is this the correct order of calls?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how you think this will work with just one value in `prev`. If I were writing this I would start with something like `class range { int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE, max = Integer.MAX_VALUE }` and then update `max` when testing a left subtree and `min` when testing a right subtree

Comment: well, you offer a different solution.. to see whether the whole left sub tree is smaller than the root, and the same goes for the right sub tree. I'm asking about this one. should be OK keeping track of only 1 prev when using in-order traversal method.